# Quadratic formula- calculator gives an answer but cannot do it manually

Tags: quadratics, quadratic-forms

Embarrassing but I have this equation:

[image]

If I use my calculator's quadratic mode I get the correct answer.

However, if I try to do it manually I get a problem because 16 - 4 x 4 x 840.15 gives a negative number, which I cannot square root?

Comment: The discriminant is $b^2 - 4ac$. You have the sign wrong.

Comment: You wrote $840(.159)$, which in standard notation means $840 \times 0.159.$ Is that what you intended to write? (This is not the reason you computed the discriminant wrong, but it is a possible notational error that can get you in trouble.)

Comment: Your mistake is that $16 - (4 \times 4\times -840) = 16 - (- 16 \times 840) = 16 + 16 \times 840 \neq 16 - 16 \times 840.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check the sign of
the term $c=-840*.158$ is negative
and the formula $$b^2-4ac$$